# How to delete a user via REST

Tags: 7, users, services

I'm trying to delete user account via REST API.

Here is my code:

```
// .xml asks for xml data in response.
$service_url = 'http://www.example.com/rest/user/login';

$post_data = [
  'username' => 'test',
  'password' => 'pass',
];

// Format post data as application/x-www-form-urlencoded.
$post_data = http_build_query($post_data, '', '&');

// Set up the request.
$curl = curl_init($service_url);

// Have curl_exec return a string.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
// Do a POST.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
// POST this data.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
// Output to command line
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);

// Make the request.
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$http_code = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($curl);

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
$session_cookie = $xml->session_name . '=' . $xml->sessid;

// Get token.
$curl_get = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl_get, [
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
  CURLOPT_URL            => 'http://www.example.com/services/session/token',
]);
$csrf_token = curl_exec($curl_get);
curl_close($curl_get);

// A user ID.
$id = 1500;
// The token.
$token = $csrf_token;

// Set up the curl resource
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/rest/user/$id?access_token=$token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");

$response = curl_exec($ch);

// Close curl resource to free up system resources.
curl_close($ch);
```

It returns:

> Access denied for user anonymous

How do I need to write the code to delete a user?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to login:

```
$loginData = ['username' => 'yourusername', 'password' => 'yourpassword'];

$ch = curl_init("http://pathtodrupal.com/endpoint/user/login.json");

curl_setopt_array($ch, [
  CURL_OPT              => TRUE,
  CURLOPTRETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER    => ['Content-Type: application/json'],
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS    => json_encode($loginData),
]);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

$responseData = json_decode($response, TRUE);
```

Once you send a POST request to login you get the following response back:

> {u'session_name': u'SESScxx45656f30', u'sessid':
>   u'mOE9NdG6Bk3EADSvKJHGGy8jgkQ', u'token':
>   u'-HVkXhARIynpmJxow5NUIYTRXSc', u'user': {u'status': u'1', u'picture':
>   u'0', u'uuid': u'514c987e7-15f0-43cc-9c6f-53279c216f30', u'uid': u'1',
>   u'language': u'', u'created': u'1310006971', u'init':
>   u'morinfo@dbasepu.com', u'timezone': u'America/New_York', u'access':
>   u'1429109927', u'theme': u'', u'roles': {u'2': u'authenticated user'},
>   u'signature': u'', u'signature_format': u'1', u'mail':
>   u'mor@morinfo.com', u'login': 1429111638, u'data': {u'ckeditor_width':
>   u'100%', u'form_build_id': u'form-60703ffc3';lk6c0fe03cebe9',
>   u'ckeditor_lang': u'en', u'ckeditor_show_toggle': u't',
>   u'last_category_id': 1, u'ckeditor_auto_lang': u't',
>   u'ckeditor_default': u't', u'site_access': {u'1': u'1'},
>   u'last_site_id': 1}, u'name': u'bewmrn'}}

In your subsequent requests you want set the the set in the header the X-CSRF-Token to `$response['token']` and Cookie to `$response['session_name'].=.$response['sessid']`. This should work.